# What are the best practices and methods to classify a time-dependent variable?

Tags: r, time-series, classification, prediction

Imagine we are collecting some feature values (like temperature, pressure etc.) every now and then and we also record the status of an equipment (which could be healthy or faulty); like below. Status of the equipment at each time depends on the series of event that has happened to it; so in order to classify the status of the equipment at time t; we have to look at what the predictor values are at time t; as well as how the predictor values behaved over the time until time t.

```
                 time temperature   pressure  status
1 2011-07-27 18:33:57 -1.26352788 -4.5068982 healthy
2 2011-07-27 16:55:54  1.32264716  1.1729150 healthy
3 2011-07-27 10:14:22  0.09091158  2.4678387  faulty
4 2011-07-27 08:20:32 -1.91443009 -0.1447071 healthy
5 2011-07-27 08:19:09  0.33651122  0.8463276 healthy
...
```

I have two questions.

First, what would be the best practices or methods to use to predict the status of the equipment at each event?

Second, if we want to use a regular classification model like random forests, what sort of transformation or preprocessing can be used to make this data classification-model friendly, while being able to capture the time dependency and the dependency on previous values that the predictors have got?

The data size is almost 10M by 300.

Comment: Is a single measurement at time moment $t$ sufficient to infer the state of the system - healthy or faulty? Or, do you also need some $k$ previous measurements to say about the current state of the system?

Comment: No, it actually depends on some k previous measurements; as well as the measurement at time t. Also, I need to note that k is unknown; and can be anything.

Comment: A Recurrent Neural Network might be a good candidate to model this. And you also got 10M examples, which is a fair amount.

Comment: Thanks! I'll take a look at it. Do you have any recommendation for my second question?